# nginx as reverse proxy for SMTP: How to send information to upstream server

Tags: nginx, smtp

I've set up nginx as reverse proxy for SMTP. My nginx setup is able to do the following:

- Take user input
- Authenticate the user via a yapache server
- Receive upstream server's ip from the auth server
- Connect to the upstream server
- Establish SMTP connection with upstream server and hand over the message.

But message delivery fails as my SMTP implementation requires client-IP and user-id which are not passed via regular SMTP commands (my user-id is different than MAIL FROM). How do I pass this information to my backend server?